# loader required to build this code?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to build the following code (from material-ui website) with webpack, but I am getting a SyntaxError on `handleClose` and `handleToggle` lines. I have enable `es2015` and `react` babel presets in package.json. Do I need to enable another preset to support this syntax?

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class DrawerUndockedExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Open Drawer"
          onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
        />
        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          width={200}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/MenuBar.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/simon/Desktop/rockstart
-client/src/components/MenuBar.jsx: Unexpected token (24:16)
  22 |   }
  23 |
> 24 |   _handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.
open});
     |                 ^
  25 |
  26 |   _handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});
  27 |
```

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: Sounds like you need `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`?

Comment: Add the presets section of your package.json

Comment: @loganfsmyth That was the answer! thanks a lot.